# Organizing data in java (on a mac)

Tags: java, storage

I'm writing a tool to analyze stock market data. For this I download data and then save all the data corresponding to a stock as a `double[][]` 20*100000 array in a data.bin on my hd, I know I should put it in some database but this is simply performance wise the best method.

Now here is my problem: I need to do updates and search on the data:
Updates: I have to append new data to the end of the array as time progresses.
Search: I want to iterate over different data files to find a minimum or calculate moving averages etc.

I could do both of them by reading the whole file in and update it writing or do search in a specific area... but this is somewhat overkill since I don't need the whole data.

So my question is: Is there a library (in Java) or something similar to open/read/change parts of the binary file without having to open the whole file? Or searching through the file starting at a specific point?

Comment: Does java work differently on Mac?

Comment: @leppie Nope not when using pure java libs

Answer (score 0):

RandomAccessFile allows seeking into particular position in a file and updating parts of the file or adding new data to the end without rewriting everything. See the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at Random Access Files:

Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

... but you will still need to figure out the exact positions you want to read in a binary file.

You might want to consider moving to a database, maybe a small embedded one like H2 (http://www.h2database.com)

Comment: Ive tried H2 but its not what I was looking for. Well random acces seems like an option thank u